# Show that an analytic function is always negative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I want to show the following function is negative for $z\in [0,1)$:
$$f(z) = -1 + z^2(z-1) + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2+1}. $$

By Tauberian theorem, I know that $\lim_{z\to 1^-}f(z)=0$. We can also estimate $f$ by truncating the series for $z$ away from 1.  I also know that $\lim_{z\to 1^-} f(z)=1$ so there is a close enough neighborhood of $1$ that $f$ is always negative. However, I want to give more details to show the negativity of the function $f$. I have included a plot of $f$ below.

[image]

Comment: die you intend to write "I also know that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0^+}f(z) = -1$"?

Comment: iirc for $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ with $a_n \rightarrow 0$ monotonically you can estimate the remainder $|\sum_{N+1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n|$ by $|a_N|$ . Did you alredy check whether that helps?